# htaccess help! wildcard subdomain rewrite rule to a specific folder for only some subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Through a little research I came up with an htaccess rewrite rule in my development directory that takes a wildcard subdomain to its matching instance name in my development folder. I will admit I know little to nothing about this so help is really needed. So the current htaccess behaves as such:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

**example**

```
instance_folder_name.mydomain.com
```

redirects to

```
public_html/development/instance_folder_name
```

this works great because it allows me to have development websites in the development directory and i dont have to be constantly creating subdomains for each site.

the problem I am having is how to approach the following scenerio:

I use virtual domains as an add on component in Joomla so that several domains are being managed by one single Joomla install. So i may have the following subdomains...

```
client1.mydomain.com
client2.mydomain.com
client3.mydomain.com
```

that all need to go to

```
/public_html/development/client1
```

I guess what i need is a general rule on how to handle all wildcard subdomains, but with exceptions for client1, client2, client3 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a separate rules for these 3 subdomains and add an exclusion condition in the older rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(client1|client2|client3)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!client1/).*)$ /client1/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(client1|client2|client3)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```